# DBMS_RANDOM installed by default or not?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c

I need to execute a SQL script to create a function.
This function uses DBMS_RANDOM.STRING method. It throws an error like

Sentence in SQL Function:

```
SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U', CODELENGTH) INTO CODEGEN FROM DUAL;
```

In DEV environment the script works perfectly and the function its created without compilation errors. But in preProd environment the Indus team always provide me error messages about this function. Finally seems that this class (DBMS_RANDOM) it's not installed.

Error message:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
15/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
15/12    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DBMS_RANDOM"."STRING": invalid identifier
```

It's DBMS_RANDOM class in a package/library which should be installed ?
If the answer it's YES, there is any QUERY to obtain installed packages/libraries?

We are using Oracle 19c in all environments.

Comment: "always provide me error messages " --- what error message exactly?

Comment: Added, sorry i thought with the description was enough

Comment: dbms_random is always installed by default. if you want to check, you can query `SELECT *
   FROM dba_objects
  WHERE object_name = 'DBMS_RANDOM'
    AND object_type = 'PACKAGE'` . If you don't see it, talk to your DBA about re-running `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/catproc.sql` which will rebuild all supplied packages. If you do see it, by default execute privs are granted to PUBLIC which means everybody can use it. Check `SELECT *
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE table_name = 'DBMS_RANDOM'` to see that that grant is there. If not, ask your DBA to provide the grant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBMS_RANDOM` is there; I presume that it's just that your user in preProd database doesn't have required privileges. It would certainly have helped if you posted which error you got. Talk to DBA and ask them to

```
grant execute on dbms_random to your_username;
```

Answer (score 0):

`DBMS_RANDOM` should exist on every Oracle database and should be granted to `PUBLIC`, which allows every user to call the package. While a simple statement like `grant execute on dbms_random to public;` will solve the immediate problem, you should also look for the root cause because this problem is a sign of other problems.

Missing privileges on `DBMS_RANDOM` are most likely caused by someone in your organization running obsolete security or audit rules. Every Oracle database audit I've ever seen was ultimately derived from the Defense Information Systems Agency's [DISA] Security Technical Implementation Guide [STIG]. In the [Oracle Database 11.2g Security Technical Implementation Guide](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/oracle_database_11.2g/), there is a rule named ["Execute permission must be revoked from PUBLIC for restricted Oracle packages"](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/oracle_database_11.2g/2021-12-13/finding/V-219701). That rule recommends removing public access to many popular packages, including `DBMS_RANDOM`.

The rule is stupid. It removes random functionality because "DBMS_RANDOM: allows encrypting of data without requiring safe management of encryption keys." Hey, why not remove the multiplication operator while we're at it? That functionality can also be used for poorly encrypting data.

Luckily, we can simply ignore that rule because it does not exist in the [most recent STIG for Oracle 12c](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/oracle_database_12c/). You might want to talk to a DBA, ask them to update their audit scripts, and grant execute on these packages back to public: DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE, DBMS_JOB, DBMS_LOB, DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT, DBMS_RANDOM, DBMS_SQL, DBMS_SYS_SQL, UTL_FILE, UTL_HTTP, UTL_SMTP, UTL_TCP.